# Passing model parts between views in Angular (ng-repeat/ng-include)

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, angularjs-ng-include

EDIT: Here is the plunker to this topic: (http://plnkr.co/edit/yDPEBPgvBCEKXQiwEjoh?p=preview)

I've some nested data-structure in my controller.

```
A
 a
     1
     2
 b
     1
```

Via ng-repeat I get a and b (I only need their length).

Via ng-includ I include a second ng-repeat in a partial file.

This partial file should get the next node in the structure (e.g. 1 & 2).

How can I pass to my partial file the part of the desired model?

Here is the plunker to this topic: (http://plnkr.co/edit/yDPEBPgvBCEKXQiwEjoh?p=preview)

Comment: have you tried using $parent property

Comment: how should I do that? I miss the right syntax..

Comment: Could you give an example of what values of model, would you pass to partial file.
In fact, as you do not have parent-child controllers you can use model in partial as if it was part of the main html itself

Comment: see the plunkr http://plnkr.co/edit/yDPEBPgvBCEKXQiwEjoh?p=preview

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing the single quotes while including template partial, because of which your template is not rendering.

```
<div ng-include="'_roles.html'"></div>
```

Comment: Angular should show a error message in these cases :)

Comment: What if `_roles` is an object in your `$scope` and `html` is property on that object which stores path of your template as string ;)

Comment: ________ :) _________

Answer (score 0):

Look this:

You forgot to put single quotes:

`<div ng-include="'_roles.html'"></div>`

```js
angular.module('myApp',[]).controller('MyController', ['$scope', function ($scope) {

    $scope.data = [
        {
            "id": 10,
            "name": "Platform A",
            "roles": [
                {
                    "id": 1,
                    "name": "Project Manager"
                },
                {
                    "id": 2,
                    "name": "Administrator"
                }
            ],
            "del": true
        },
        {
            "id": 12,
            "name": "Platform B",
            "roles": [
                {
                    "id": 2,
                    "name": "Administrator"
                }
            ],
            "del": true
        }
    ];
    
    
}]);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="myApp">

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
  <link data-require="bootstrap@*" data-semver="3.3.5" rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
  <link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" data-semver="3.1.1" data-require="bootstrap-css@3.1.1" />
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.min.js" data-semver="2.1.4" data-require="jquery@*"></script>
  <script data-require="angular.js@1.4.7" data-semver="1.4.7" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.4.7/angular.min.js"></script>
 

  <script src="script.js"></script>
</head>

<body ng-controller="MyController">

  <table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>
          <!-- COLLAPSE  -->
        </th>
        <th>ID</th>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Roles</th>
        <th>Deletion</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
     <tbody>
      <tr ng-repeat="model in data">
        <td>
          <!-- COLLAPSE -->
        </td>
        <td>{{model.id}}</td>
        <td>{{model.name}}</td>
        <td>
          {{model.roles.length}}
          <div ng-include="'_roles.html'"></div>
        </td>
        <td>{{model.del}}</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
    
  </table>
</body>
<script type="text/ng-template" id="_roles.html">
<table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover">
  <tbody>
    <tr ng-repeat="roles in model.roles">
      <td>
        <!-- COLLAPSE -->
      </td>
      <td>{{roles.id}}</td>
      <td>{{roles.name}}</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
</script>
</html>
```